# np.where is not working inside function but outside it is working

Tags: python, numpy

Below is my code what I'm trying.
I have a vocabulary and model pickle file I'm loading both of them and 
checking for the prediction but after that I want score also so for that I'm using the following code in which where to find the index of the predicted string in the model.classes_ I'm using the np.where module but that is not working inside the function but outside it is working.

My Code:

```
    import os

    import numpy as np
    from sklearn.externals import joblib

    def predict_score(vect, model, search_key):
        prediction = ''
        index = ''
        score = ''

        prediciton = model.predict(vect.transform([search_key]))[0]
        index = np.squeeze(np.where(model.classes_ == prediction)) 
        # this line block is giving **(array([], dtype=int64),)**
        score = model.predict_proba(vect.transform([search_key]))[:, 
         index][0]

         return prediciton, score


    vect = joblib.load(r'vect.pkl')
    model = joblib.load(r'model.pkl')

    print(predict_score(vect, model, 'Help to predict me'))
    print(np.where(model.classes_ == predict_score(vect, model, 'Help to 
    predict me')[0])) 
    # this is working as expected **(array([42], dtype=int64),)**
```

Comment: What do you mean with "not working"? Can you post the corresponding arrays?

Comment: its there in the comments np.squeeze(np.where(model.classes_ == prediction)) inside the function giving the blank array but outside after function cal it is giving array with index of the string

Comment: I don't see a call of `np.where` inside a function. Maybe you need to fix indentation?

Comment: Yes intendation was wrong